# Error on removing items from ListView

Tags: java, listview, arraylist, javafx

I have two ListViews, each being populated by a separate ArrayList. I'm trying to make it so that in left ListView, double clicking an item copies it to the right, and double clicking in the right removes the item. Whenever I try to add an item, I get a whole slew of errors, and nothing changes. Removing items works about half the time; It's really weird, sometimes when I run it things will remove just fine, and other times, again, I just get a whole host of errors. Some code:

```
//Right list view
    ListView<String> lv_right = new ListView<>
    (FXCollections.observableArrayList(selectedSpells));
    lv_right.setPrefSize(175, 598);
    lv_right.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);


    //Double clicking in right list
    lv_right.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && event.getClickCount() == 2 &&
               (event.getTarget() instanceof Labeled || ((BorderPane) event.getTarget()).getChildren().size() > 0)) {

                //Removing items from right list
                String item = lv_right.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                lv_right.getItems().remove(item);
             }    
        }
    });
```

I have the exact same thing right now for the left ListView, with the exception of `lv_left.getItems().remove(item);` being replaced with `cleric_cantrips.add(item);` which never works at all.

The slew of errors:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledText cannot be cast to javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
at spell_manager$1.handle(spell_manager.java:52)
at spell_manager$1.handle(spell_manager.java:1)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Normally junk like this means that there's a problem with the code itself, but I've no errors there, so I figured I'd add this here in case anyone wanted to see it rather than wait for someone to ask if they did need it.

I'm honestly at a loss for what to do. I'm still new to using JavaFX...thanks in advance guys!

Comment: You are assuming that if the target of the event is not a labeled, then it must be a `BorderPane`. Clearly that is not the case, and your code is firing a class cast exception. What is that condition supposed to be doing? (What does "I've no errors there" mean?)

Comment: The "I've no errors" just meant that I don't have any in the editor and the code runs fine, no startup errors. And as for as the labeled and BorderPane issue, I'll be honest, I don't really know why the labeled bit is there. I got that line from another post here, and it worked, soo...like I said, I'm new to JavaFX and I'm piecing things together as I go.

Comment: Well you could hardly expect to get a runtime error if the code didn't compile. Looking at other people's code and copying it is a good way to learn, but the idea is you're supposed to understand what it does. Blindly copying it without knowing what it is doing is not going to teach you anything. The parts you are missing are about casting and the `instanceof` operator. I recommend you read up on that and understand why it was used in the original post. Questions of the form "I copied some code I don't understand, why doesn't it work?" usually get fairly short shrift here.

Comment: I understand that. But the reason I came here is because it's usually easier to figure things out with someone explaining things rather than reading documentation, which, while helpful, can sometimes be hard to convert to your specific project. Maybe that's just me, but I find specific help over general is better.

Comment: I can't see any possible reason for including the second line of the `if` condition. What are you actually testing for? If there's no reason for it, why don't you remove it and see if it works?

Comment: Thank you for that. I suppose I should have just removed what I didn't understand off the bat, and if that failed then do as you said and read up on things first. And as usual after a fix, I feel dumb as it usually always turns out to be something simple I'm missing. Thanks again man.

Answer (score 0):

Beacause when you used `||` ,the target can not be **labeled** and **borderPane** in the same time,for example when you make double click to **labeled**, the target here is labeled ,after that we move to other choice you tried to cast **labeled** to **borderPane** so you need to write each condition alone like this

```
 lv_right.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && event.getClickCount() == 2)
           {
             if(event.getTarget() instanceof Labeled) {

            //Removing items from right list
            String item = lv_right.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            lv_right.getItems().remove(item);
         }   
            if(event.getTarget() instanceof BorderPane) {
             BorderPane border=(BorderPane)event.getTarget;
            if(border.getChildren().size>0)
             {
            //Removing items from right list
            String item = lv_right.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            lv_right.getItems().remove(item);
           }
           }    
    }
});
```